# How to validate server side code in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I am getting some value from server , if the value is false i need to show alert message on UI without refreshing or postbacking the page.

What i am doing currently is i get the value from server i declare one hidden control and store that value in hidden control and in aspx page i write one JS method to check if that value is false show the alert message, but the problem is i have to do this on click on a button which is present in code behind 
so as soon as i click on that button JS code gets executed before i get value from server.

```
    function fnvalidation() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=hdnCtrl.ClientID%>").value == false) {
            alert('Please submit it again');
            return false;
}
}
```

On page load i am registering like this :

```
 btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return fnvalidation()");
```

C# Code :

```
bValidate = CommonUtility.ValidateOutput();
hdnCtrl.Value = bValidate.ToString();//Storing value in hidden variable
if(bvalidate == false)
{
//Call javascript method fnvalidation
}
```

How to call this JS method correctly when value is false coming from server ?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the button *need* to be an `asp:Button`?  If it's just an `input type="button"` then you can respond to it with JavaScript without it automatically posting anything to the server.  Also, is the value present when the page initially loads?  Or does the page need to fetch the value from the server when the button is pressed?  If the former, just examine the value that's already there in the hidden field.  If the latter, don't use the hidden field at all and create an AJAX handler server-side which the client code can call to fetch the value.

Comment: Yes it is server side button asp button, the value needs to be fetched when button is pressed not on page load.can you tell me how to create AJAX handler server side an example please..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

inside your condition if(bvalidate == false) condition like  then no need to rely on the value to be set ( i.e in java script function you can remove checking the hidden field value simply alert the user.
Also you can remove this code  btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return fnvalidation()")

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "validateFnscript", "fnvalidation()", 
true);
```

Comment: Please let me know what lines of code you put in javascript function. Assuming that btnSave button click handler in the code behind , first validates , if valid procceeds for save else call the javacript function to alert. btnsave should ideally post back if no client click are attached that returns false that prevents the postback.

Comment: function fnvalidation() {       
            alert('Please submit it again');
            return false;

} My requirement is page should get refreshed and should not postback too.

Comment: 'My requirement is page should get refreshed and should not postback too' I am having little difficulty in understanding this requirement. if you are looking some thing like the below. in your javascript function add the following line after alert statement . window.location.href = 'http://SamepageUrlyoucangive' and no need to keep return false statement

Comment: Sorry...My requirement is page should not get refreshed and should not postback too...on displaying that alert popup when condition is false

Comment: Oh .. Ok .. if that is the case then you need to follow what David has suggested. you must depend on AJAX to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If your page needs to fetch data from the server without refreshing the page, then you need to use AJAX.  Which comes down to two things:

1. Create an AJAX endpoint in server-side code.
2. Consume that AJAX endpoint from client-side code.

The server-side code likely has several options.  HTTP Handlers, empty ASPX pages which clear and response and set a new content type, maybe even Web Methods?  It's been a *long time* since I've used WebForms, so I'm not 100% sure what the recommended approach is right now.  But [I *think* Web Methods are what you're looking for](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).  So your code-behind would have something like this:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page 
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetValue()
    {
        return "some value";
    }
}
```

Then, assuming you're using jQuery for example, you would call that endpoint from your client-side code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/GetValue"
}).done(function (data) {
    // respond to the value in "data"
}).error(function () {
    // there was an error
});
```

Now your client-side button click handler can use that, or something like it, to fetch the value from the server.  If that's *all* that button needs to do then don't make it an `asp:Button` but instead just an `input type="button"` so that it doesn't post back the whole page.  Keeping it as a server-side button would mean canceling the event propagation in JavaScript, which gets ugly with asynchronous operations because there's no immediate way to *resume* event propagation, you'd have to manually invoke the post back.